# VBA Convert year "yyyy" to single digit year

Tags: vba, date, excel

I am trying to convert a date `mm/dd/yyyy` eg. `05/27/2014` to a "single" digit year which will return "4" in the example.

I know you can do `Format("05/27/2014", "yy")` which will return two digit year.

However I am in finance and some products uses only the last digit of year. Such as `HCH5C` the `5` representing year 2015.

I think I can combine Right() and Format()

```
Right(Format("05/27/2014", "yy"),1)
```

But it seems a bit excessive and I am wondering if there is a smarter way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `MOD(<num>, <divisor>)` function where `num` Is your year and `divisor` is `10`. This will divide your year by ten and return the remainder to you.

See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/mod-function-HP010342698.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the Modulo-Operator like:

```
2014 Mod 10
```

then it will always work